# Where does getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName() pull from?

Tags: java, windows

With say a Windows 2012 Server R2 system, does getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName() pull from a certain registry entry, a file or does it go out and do something like a nslookup against the IP of the system with a dns server?